# Regex to repeat indentation in sed

Tags: regex, sed, solaris

This is what I want to do:

If I encounter a pattern like

```
someVarX: val1
```

I want to insert

```
someVarY: val2
```

on the next line

**...BUT HERE IS THE CATCH:**

**someVarX: val1** can have a number preceding blank spaces (indentation) counting anywhere between 0 and N and  I also want to repeat that exact indentatation on the next line.  So if **someVarX: val1** has 3 preceding blank spaces, then I also want **someVarY: val2** to have 3 preceding blank spaces.

This is what I tried:

```
s/\n( +)someVarX: val1/\n${1}someVarX: val1\n${1}someVarY: val2/
```

hoping that ${1} would insert the capture group from the search pattern into the replace string but got:

```
sed: command garbled: ...
```

The OS os SunOS 5.10.  I couldn't run `sed --version`, it told me the option --version was illegal.

Any idea?

Comment: capture groups are referenced like `\1`. Also, in your match pattern, is the '\n` meant to a new-line? This won't work unless you are operating on the hold  buffer. For what you appear to be attempting (sample input and required output in your question makes this sort of thing so much easier to help with, now we have to assume we know how you want this to work).

Comment: yes, `\n` is the new line.  how else i can instruct it to insert a new line?

Comment: 1. please edit your question to include results of `uname` and `sed --version`. Some seds allow `\n` in the replacement part. My objection to `\n` is in the first part, the pattern matching in `s/\n( +) someVar...`.  2. Sed relies on `\n` to separate each line for processing, it won't be at the being of the line. The only place an `\n` will work on the pattern matching side is when you have saved a line into the hold buffer.... so ... 3. Are you showing us your complete sed script? Good luck.

Comment: updated:  The OS os SunOS 5.10.  I couldn't run sed --version, it told me the option --version was illegal.

Comment: most people assume the whole world revolves around Linux. I think @Thor's portable answer should work with Sun. (You'll get more timely responses to use a tag for Solaris and including sample input and required out put.) Good luck

Comment: added the solaris tag.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what finally worked:

```
        s/^\( *\)someVarX: val1/&\
\1someVarY: val2/
```

It had to be done on two lines of a sed S&R spec file, let's call it `snrspec.sed`, which also contained other S&R instructions:

```
1,/^END/{
        s/ABC/XYZ/

        ...

        s/^\( *\)someVarX: val1/&\
\1someVarY: val2/

}
```

and then I called sed:

```
sed -f snrspec.sed inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

However, I would prefer to do it in a single line, if anyone knows how to, as it would obviously be more elegant.  But the above worked and I performed my massive S&R operation.

Comment: it's not obvious at all that doing multiple replacements on a single line would be more elegant, I think running the script from a file is a much more sensible approach.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your input resembles this:

```
<< EOF > infile
someVarX: val1
   someVarX: val1
 someVarX: val1
    someVarX: val1
EOF
```

You can accomplish it like this (tested with GNU sed ERE):

```
<infile sed -r 's/^( *)someVarX: .*/&\n\1someVarY: val2/'
```

Same thing with BRE and more portable options (also tested with FreeBSD sed):

```
sed '/^ *someVarX: .*/ { G; s/^\( *\)someVarX: .*/&\1someVarY: val2/; }' infile
```

Output:

```
someVarX: val1
someVarY: val2
   someVarX: val1
   someVarY: val2
 someVarX: val1
 someVarY: val2
    someVarX: val1
    someVarY: val2
```

Note, use `^` to anchor the regular expression at the beginning of the line, not `\n` as sed never sees the newlines in the input. Also use `*`, unless you always have space at the beginning of the line.

The ampersand (`&`) in the replacement is substituted by the whole match, and the backreference (`\1`) inserts the right amount of space.

Comment: I am setting the regex in a sed S&R file along with other regexes (that work).  i tried this and it didn't work:  `s/( *)someVarX: val1/\1someVarX: val1&\n\1someVarX: val1/`

Comment: @foampile: are you using basic or extended regular expressions? Also note you're duplicating `someVarX`, `&` will expand to `\1someVarX: val1`.

Comment: after changing to `s/^( *)someVarX: .*/&\n\1someVarY: val2/`, i still got `command garbled`

Comment: @foampile: try the more portable version I just added.

Comment: where is the new line insertion in the the version?

Comment: appears as though my version of sed doesn't like specing capture groups in parenths `^ *` matches preceding blank  spaces at the beginning of a line but not `^( *)`

Comment: @foampile: The `G` command adds a newline to pattern space followed by the contents of hold space, but as HS is empty, only a newline is added.

Comment: the G entered a new line before every line, not just the ones matching the pattern -- doubling the number of lines in the file :(

Comment: see the answer i just posted

Comment: @foampile: You need to make the block (`{...}`) dependent on `/^ *someVarX: .*/`, sounds like you dropped that part.

Comment: Hold space is a buffer that sed has available, it's initially empty so we can (mis)use it for adding the newline.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any sed:

```
sed -n 'p;s/^\([ \t]*\)someVarX: val1/\1someVarY: val2/p' file
```

and if you want something more extensible, here's the awk solution:

```
awk '1; /^[ \t]*someVarX: val1/{ sub(/[^ \t].*/,"someVarY: val2"); print}' file
```

Comment: see the answer i just posted

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you(GNU sed):

```
sed '/someVarX: val1/{h;G;s//someVarY: val2/2}' file
```